# Drupal removing pointless span classes

Tags: drupal, class, module, html

I am working on a Drupal site here: http://selkirk.treethink.net

I have a couple modules that are firing out an insane amount of span classes, which you can see in the source code there.

Nice menus is one of these and is causing 60% of them. I need to prevent these modules from doing this but I can't seem to find the code that's doing this in the module source.

Do I have to write something to cancel it out or override the module theming? I'm not sure how to do this though as this is my first Drupal project.

Here is the nice menus page: http://drupal.org/project/nice_menus

Thanks,

Wade

Comment: I'm going to try something different for the drop down menus but there will still be extra classes floating around.

Comment: span classes were still there when I removed the nice menu module. Not sure what is going on!

Comment: It seems it is Views doing this, not sure how to override it yet.

Comment: Are you by any chance using devel themer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd agree with googletorp's comment.  It sounds like the source of the spans is the Devel module's "Theme Developer".  It's a very handy module, but it adds a span around every theme call in order to do its work.

The Devel module provides a block titled "Development".  Go to *Administer > Site building > Blocks* and place that somewhere handy in one of your regions.  It has a link for quickly toggling the Theme Developer module.  I'd only enable it to check on something, and then immediately disable it again.

If it is actually Views layout that you need to override, you can edit your view and click on "Theme: Information" for a list of views templates you can override for that view/display.